# Lodash module not found + webpack

Tags: webpack, lodash

I try use the library ladash but I´m getting the next error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'lodash' in
```

I import the library as:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

This is the webpack config:

```
{
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  options: {
     plugins: ['lodash'],
     presets: [['env', { modules: false, targets: { node: 4 } }]]
  }
}

......
......
plugins: [
   new LodashModuleReplacementPlugin,
   new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin
]
```

and this is my package json dependencies:

[image]

Comment: did you run `npm install` ?

Comment: Did you try using `typings install lodash`

Comment: I did npm install --save lodash

Comment: you are right, I looked in the node_module folder and the lodash module was not so I did npm install again and now it is working

Answer (score 1):

Running `npm install` will solve your error!