# Modules not found in webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm using `webpack 4.41.5` and ran `npm install d3 --save` which installs `v5.15.0`.

In one of my scripts, I import d3 using:

```
const d3 = require('d3');
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
//...more imports
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = [{
    //...config stuff

    resolve:{},

    plugins: [
        // ...more modules
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ d3: 'd3',})
    ]
}]
```

I followed these [two](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33090648/12769175) and the resulting error message looks like this:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/d3-array/src/index.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './ascending' in '[work_dir]/node_modules/d3-array/src'
     @ ./node_modules/d3-array/src/index.js 2:0-49 2:0-49
     @ ./node_modules/d3/index.js
     @ ./src/index.js

 ~~ approx 1 billion more errors of the same kind
```

I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47110025/lodash-module-not-found-webpack) because it looked to be the same error, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding `extensions: ['.js']` to the `resolve` property in `webpack.config.js`